# How can I force mysql to crash itself

Tags: mysql, crash

I am looking for the way to get mysql crashed itself. 
I have  googled for it but no luck. 
I have tried the [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32125), but not able to crash the mysql

Is there any good to make mysql crashed itself.

Comment: Why you are trying to crash mysql?

Comment: I want test my mysql failover manually. Also I want to know the ways and case studies to upgrade myself